# cellForRowAtIndexPath not being called required number of times

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

The functionality that I am trying to achieve is that first I am showing two rows in a `UITableView` which is showing perfectly. Then on `didSelectRowAtIndexpath:`, I am adding the `numberOfRows` in the `UITableView`, for which I am reloading the `UITableView` after adding the `numberOfRows` and the required data.

My problem is that I am passing the new number of rows in the `numberOfRowsInSection:` (which I have checked, it is passing correctly) but `cellForRowAtIndexpath:` is called only two times after that, which is the previous `numberOfRows` value.

My Code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.currentSubCategoryRows;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
   // My code for cell construction goes here
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   [self.arrWithAdditionalValues addObjectsFromArray:[self.dictSubCategoriesLevel3 objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",rowOpened]]];
   self.currentSubCategoryRows += self.arrWithAdditionalValues.count;
            [tableView reloadData];
}
```

What could be the reason?

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Can you show the code here how exactly you increased the number of rows?

Comment: Please show us the code.

Comment: I have edited my question with the code...

Comment: It is recommended that you tightly couple the return from `numberOfRows...` to an actual model (and not try to manage it independently). Whatever model you use in `cellForRow...` should have  (for example) it's `count` returned from `numberOfRows...`. It is quite risky that you will loose parity between the two and crash your app :-/

Comment: Is your array ,i.e. , arrWithAdditionalValues is updating values? What does it contain before and after the call of didSelectRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: @AJS: Yes it is updating as required, also the number of rows is correctly returned from numberOfRowsInSection, but cellForRow is not called.

Comment: I have tested the situation.It works fine for me.If numberOfRows are increasing it must be called for that count.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution.

As I was resizing my `UITableView` as per its number of rows in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, that's why the next part of the `UITableView` was not visible, and for the part of the `UITableView` which is not visible, `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is never called.

Sorry to bother you all.

Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Answer (score 4):

cellForRowAtIndexPath: is only called as soon as is needed for drawing. You have to build that method without controlling when it will be invoked.

Comment: I think you are right, as soon as I scroll the table view, it is updated, but what if I want to update it in reloadData?

Comment: If you need to process cellForRowAtIndexPath: then you are in a mistake. That method is not for your necessities but for the system. Let it invoke the method when it needs and as many times as it needs. Your calculations that are needed to be done must be done in other methods that you can fire when you need.

Answer (score 2):

Try to Reload table in `viewWillAppear`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [tableview reloadData];
    }
```

Comment: But I want to reload it from didSelectRowAtIndexpath: as on the selection of the row I want to add new rows...